# Is the jlink --module-path an ordered path?

Tags: java, java-9, jlink

I have been experimenting with migrating my programs to **jlink** via experiments with a Hello World and a Hello JFX World program.  The examples I had followed seem to specify **--add-modules** when it comes to running the program.  I do not understand why the program should need information supplied at run-time that it had at jlink time.

I have now successfully built a simple **jlink** Hello World program that will run without having **--add-modules** on the command line. The trick was to change the order of the modules specified on the jlink module path.  I don't know why this worked.

Where is this jlink behaviour specified or described in JDK-9, JDK-10 or JDK-11 documentation?  How should one go about constructing the module-path?

*Aside: This sort of ordered linking was common 30 years ago when I used to link Fortran IV and Macro-11 programs on a DEC PDP-11 minicomputer. I thought to try fiddling with the ordering for jlink when I was about to give up*

module-info.java:

```
module TestFXord {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports testfxord to javafx.graphics;
}
```

TestFXord.java:

```
package testfxord;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestFXord extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

jlink command that does not produce runnable image

```
#! /bin/sh
<jdk-11-path>/bin/jlink --module-path <jdk-11-path>/jmods:<javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/javafx.base.jar:<javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/javafx.controls.jar:<javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:<javafx-jmods-11-path>:<path-to-projects>/TestFXord/dist/TestFXord.jar --add-modules TestFXord --strip-debug --launcher TestFXord=TestFXord/testfxord.TestFXord --output dist/jlink/TestFXord
```

jlink command that does build a runnable image.  Note that the  now appears immediately after the  on which it depends.

```
#! /bin/sh
    <jdk-11-path>/bin/jlink --module-path <jdk-11-path>/jmods:<javafx-jmods-11-path>:<javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/javafx.base.jar:<javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/javafx.controls.jar:<javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:<path-to-projects>/TestFXord/dist/TestFXord.jar --add-modules TestFXord --strip-debug --launcher TestFXord=TestFXord/testfxord.TestFXord --output dist/jlink/TestFXord
```

I reckon **jlink** progressively builds a symbol table, mapping symbols to addresses, working left to right down the module-path and resolves (finding the addresses for) the symbols for which it has an address and adding new symbol entries that it finds that can be used to resolve calls in later modules. If the module-path is in the right order every symbol will be resolved in this process.  If the module-path is not in the correct order there will be symbols that have not been resolved.  When it comes to running the image the user will have to add-modules to resolve the leftover symbols.

In other words I don't think jlink goes back up the list to resolve symbols in earlier modules it has just discovered.  Thinking about it, I suspect the reason this would be done is that going back to search for unresolved symbols every time you add a new module would require a much longer linking process for large applications.  Does that sound about right?

Comment: You normally only need `--add-modules` at runtime if your code is not modular (no `module-info`) or none of the modules on the modulepath explicitly require a module that you'd still like resolved. For `jlink`, `--add-modules` is necessary to tell it the root modules that it can then find all required modules from. That said, it'd help if you provided a [mcve] so we can see exactly what you did when it didn't, and did, work.

Comment: The module path specified to --module-path is a path of directories or modules. So the order does matter if you specify multiple locations that have different versions of the same module. Slaw asks for example where you need --add-modules at run-time. That would be useful to have in order to provide a useful answer.

Comment: In the example, the application says it was unable to initialize a Graphics Device:
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw

It is looking for low level library modules such as  <javafx-sdk-11-path>/lib/libprism_es2.so  Adding the javafx jmods earlier in the module-path seems to do the trick.  There must be something in the jmods.

Comment: @AlanBateman OP added examples. I answered, but is there anything you think I'm missing or mistaken about?

Comment: Reading the update suggests to me that she should have download the jmods bundle and added javafx-jmods-11.0.1 to the module path, not specific JAR files that I assume don't contain the shared libraries that JavaFX needs.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 10vc2 (now superseded), which needs the jars at the source code level to satisfy javafx import statements.  Netbeans puts the jars on the jlink module-path when I tick the create jlink box.  If I untick the box, Netbeans stops before running jlink.  I can then run the jlink command on the terminal.  I can run the jlink command without the javafx jars but specifying the jmods.  That creates a successful image as you say.  I don't think adding the javafx jars to the jlink --module-path matters apart from slowing the jlink a bit doing redundant work.

Comment: The only bit about the question not answered is, "Where is the official documentation explaining this?"

Comment: You need to use the "jmods" download when creating a run-time image with jlink. The packaged modules in the "jmods" downloads includes the native libraries so jlink will copy them into the run-time image. I assume the jlink commands that you (or NetBeans) are using results in a run-time image that is missing the native libraries.

Comment: I installed the javafx jmods when setting up JavaFX 11 but it took me a while to try adding them to the Netbeans Library entry for JavaFX that I created. Making the build work on Netbeans means being thoughtful about the order of entries in the Netbeans Library.  The javafx jmods entry needs to be at the top of the list, followed by the javafx.* module jars that my programs use.

Comment: I think the summary on this issue is that you specify javafx-jmods-11.0.1 as the module path to jlink. Do you specify the javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/*.jar because that will result in a run-time image that doesn't contain the native libraries needed by JavaFX. Maybe the JavaFX pages could be clear on that point as it is an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AlanBateman [said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240219/is-the-jlink-module-path-an-ordered-path#comment93372059_53240219):

> The module path specified to --module-path is a path of directories or modules. So the order does matter if you specify multiple locations that have different versions of the same module.

In both your examples you include the JavaFX JMOD files and JavaFX JAR files in the `--module-path`. The difference is the order you include them.

- Working example: *JMOD files are first*.

  - `jlink` will use the modules contained in the JMOD files
- Non-Working example: *JMOD files are last*.

  - `jlink` will use the modules contained in the JAR files

The JAR files shipped with the JavaFX SDK do not contain any of the necessary native code. If you link against the JAR files the resulting image will fail to execute.

The JMOD files, however, *do* contain the necessary native code. In fact, bundling native code with Java code is one of the main reasons the JMOD format was implemented. From [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261):

> The new JMOD format goes beyond JAR files to include native code, configuration files, and other kinds of data that do not fit naturally, if at all, into JAR files. JMOD files are used to package the modules of the JDK itself; they can also be used by developers to package their own modules, if desired.
>
> JMOD files can be used at compile time and link time, but not at run time. To support them at run time would require, in general, that we be prepared to extract and link native-code libraries on-the-fly. This is feasible on most platforms, though it can be very tricky, and we have not seen many use cases that require this capability, so for simplicity we have chosen to limit the utility of JMOD files in this release.

When using `jlink` you should link against the JMOD files where available. If a library doesn't provide JMOD files then link against the JAR files.

With all that said, you should remove the JavaFX JAR files from the `--module-path` altogether—they're unnecessary and cause confusion.